# How to ensure that my bitmap is in ARGB_8888 format and of the highest possible quality?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera

I have a camera app where my camera preview and captured image are of fairly low quality. I have been reading a bit about bitmaps and it recommends configuring the captured image to save in ARGB_8888 format, but none of the examples I read about really match my use case. Here is the function that executes when the picture is taken:

```
@Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        File pictureFile = Util.getOutputMediaFile(this);
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't create file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "File not found exception",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "IO Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
                    pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
            Bitmap bm1 = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            int w = bm1.getWidth();
            int h = bm1.getHeight();
            matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
            matrix.preRotate(-90);
            Bitmap adjustedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm1, 0, 0,
                    w, h, matrix, true);     //I'm tempted to put it here, but it always throws errors when I try and add Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 as an argument to createBitmap
            OutputStream outStream = null;
            // sampleimage4 is the name given to the image saved. You can give
            // any name
            File file = new File(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                // saving as a JPEG image
                adjustedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
                        outStream);
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagePreview.class);
            if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
                if (bundle != null)
                    intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
            }
            intent.putExtra("filePath", pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
            intent.putExtra("load", load);
            intent.putExtra("height", preview.getHeight());
            intent.putExtra("width", preview.getWidth());

            startActivity(intent);
            camera.startPreview();
        }
    }
```

So you hopefully can see my desire to use ARGB_8888 in that line that I have commented in the middle. But I am not sure how to implement this.

Comment: If your primary concern is quality, compress it with PNG rather than JPEG.  Or just leave it in YUV.  Are you sure that your RGB format is to blame?  Do you see something in the image that suggests poor quantization?

Comment: Its a pretty small bitmap 640 x 480 which is much less than the size of the screen. This happens when I compress with JPEG or PNG. I was thinking that argb_8888 might save more pixels, but this is just a theory. Anything to get more pixels in that bitmap would be good.

Comment: PNG is lossless RGBA 8888.  JPEG is lossy, so you expect to lose some detail, but at high quality settings it shouldn't be noticeable to the naked eye.  There's a colorspace conversion from YUV to RGB that could be losing some fidelity, but again it's not something that should be readily apparent when snapping photos.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make the bitmap save with more pixels than 640 x 480 ?

Comment: Configure the camera to capture a larger image.

Comment: It seems to do the resolution choosing during the camera preview. Does it capture images in the same resolution that it previews them in?